# Sequence Js Autoplay stops randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a [sequence js slider](http://www.sequencejs.com/documentation/) on this [page](http://bwdmedia.in/saxena/) in the testimonials section but I cannot figure out why it stops cycling/autoplaying randomly. There are no console errors or warnings.

The manual buttons still works and it randomly continues cycling too. But I don't understand why it stops in the first place.

HTML:

```
<div id="sequence">
  <ul class="seq-canvas">
    <li class="seq-in step1">
      <div class="author">
        <h3>John Doe</h3>
        <h4>Director, Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="step2">
      <div class="author">
        <h3>Jane Smith</h3>
        <h4>Lawyer, Other Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="step3">
      <div class="author">
        <h3>Alex Sparks</h3>
        <h4>Lawyer, Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="review">
        <p>"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1 class="section-title">What Our Clients Say</h1>
  <a class="seq-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="seq-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Get the Sequence element
  var sequenceElement = document.getElementById("sequence");
  var options = {
    startingStepAnimatesIn: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlayInterval: 4000,
    keyNavigation: true,
    fadeStepWhenSkipped: true
  }
  var mySequence = sequence(sequenceElement, options);
```

Comment: And what is this `sequence(...)` thing?

Comment: This is how sequence is initialized. [http://www.sequencejs.com/documentation/](http://www.sequencejs.com/documentation/)

Comment: It seems sequence stops when window loses focus - i.e. if I go to some other site and come back, then it has stopped.  You can incorporate code by setting a flag onblur and then on refocus execute the sequence code again.  That may help.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it sometimes stops even on mouse out. I'll see if i can initialize or call autoplay again

Answer (score 0):

It was the Sequence's [Autoplay](http://www.sequencejs.com/documentation/#autoplay) functionality that pauses autoplay on hover which I was able to confirm with a little code like this

```
mySequence.stopped = function() {
  console.log("Auto play stopped");
}
```

To disable this behavior I just used another ready to use option `autoPlayPauseOnHover` and that solved the problem.

```
var options = {
    startingStepAnimatesIn: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlayPauseOnHover: false,
    autoPlayInterval: 4000,
    keyNavigation: true,
    fadeStepWhenSkipped: true
  }
```

It still stops when you switch tabs but I think that's reasonable considering the performance impact that would have. I starts up automatically when you return to it.